# Getting authentication error on axios while passing basic authentication credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, axios

I've handled my server side's basic auth with nodejs, Please refer the code below.

```
module.exports = basicAuth;
// require("dotenv").config({ path: "./.env" });
require("dotenv/config");

// async function basicAuth(req, res, next) {
function basicAuth(req, res, next) {
  // check for basic auth header
  if (
    !req.headers.authorization ||
    req.headers.authorization.indexOf("Basic ") === -1
  ) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "Missing Authorization Header" });
  }

  console.log(req.headers.authorization);
  // verify auth credentials
  const base64Credentials = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
  //   console.log(base64Credentials);
  const credentials = Buffer.from(base64Credentials, "base64").toString(
    "ascii"
  );
  const [username, password] = credentials.split(":");
  // const user = await userService.authenticate({ username, password });
  let user = 0;
  if (
    username == process.env.API_USERNAME &&
    password == process.env.API_PASSWORD
  ) {
    user = 1;
  }
  if (!user) {
    return res
      .status(401)
      .json({ message: "Invalid Authentication Credentials" });
  }

  next();
}
```

I've added `app.use(cors())` in my app.js and I'm able to access all routes using basic authentication.
I've written my front end application using react and I'm using axios to fetch the data using the routes that I created. Please note the same API's work when I try to access it without using basic auth.
Below is the code for accessing data using axios.

```
try {
      require("dotenv").config();
      console.log(this.state.params);
      let urlparam = "http://localhost:5000/users/" + this.state.params;

      let result;
      result = await axios({
        url: "http://localhost:5000/users",
        method: "get",
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
          authorization: "Basic c2Fsb29uOnNhbG9vbg==",
        },
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
```

Using the above code I get:
**The requested resource requires user authentication.** 
on Edge browser and on Google chrome I get the error: 
**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/users' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**
and
**xhr.js:178 GET http://localhost:5000/users net::ERR_FAILED**

Please bear in mind I've added and used the cors middleware for all routes and it was working previously.
I even tried passing auth parameters separately like

```
auth:{username:"",password:""}
```

it still wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to include
`app.use(basicAuth)` below `app.use(cors())` in the app.js file.